# Ubuntu installed but doesn't boot: error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, grub2

I got a new PC and I'm installing Ubuntu again as a dual boot alongside Win10, but this time Ubuntu won't even boot, instead I get some errors.

I think that there is something wrong with GRUB give that when I turn on my PC Windows boots automatically; the GRUB menu never appears.

Here's what i get when I try to force boot into Ubuntu from BIOS

[image: errors when trying to boot Ubuntu from BIOS]

System information: Dell latitude, Legacy BIOS, secure boot OFF.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention being asked about choosing the boot OS when you power up or restart, I hope that you're talking about after choosing to boot with Ubuntu.

If that's the case, you might try booting with a Ubuntu-Live usb/cd again and make sure that the partition has been set as a bootable partition where your Ubuntu is installed. It's possible that it's that simple and, once set, will boot on in like you expect.

Hope this helps.
Please let us know.